# Parallel Array for a Java project

Tags: java

I have searched to see if there was a question like this already but I did not find one. So for this school project, I am supposed to make a program with arrays to look up and print the names and prices for coffee orders. I have most of the program done but I only get one dialog box to pop up and if I add an XXX it quits the system completely without giving an output. 
I know if I add some more addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: "); it would give me another pop-up window but I am still having trouble with it has I want it to give me one line at a time like if I say "Cream" it says "Cream price is $0.89" and if I enter "Vanilla" it says "Sorry we do not carry that" and when I enter "XXX" it would just says "Order total is $2.89".

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JumpinJive
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        // Declare variables.
        String addIn;        // Add-in ordered by customer.
        final int NUM_ITEMS = 5; // Named constant
        // Initialized array of add-ins.
        String addIns[] = {"Cream", "Cinnamon", "Chocolate", "Amaretto", "Whiskey"}; 
        // Initialized array of add-in prices.
        double addInPrices[] = {.89, .25, .59, 1.50, 1.75};
        boolean foundIt = false; 
        int x;            // Loop control variable.
        double orderTotal = 2.00; // All orders start with a 2.00 charge

        // Get user input.
        addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ");

        // Write the rest of the program here.
        for(int it=0; it < NUM_ITEMS; it++){
            if(addIns[it].equals(addIn)){
                //Output the product name and the price
                System.out.println("Name of the product :" + addIns[it] + "\nPrice of the product:" + addInPrices[it]);

                //Output the total for the price of the product 
                System.out.println("Total Price of the product :"+ (orderTotal + addInPrices[it]));

                //If foundIt is true
                foundIt = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //See if it is found 
        if(foundIt)
        {
            //Prints a Error Message
            System.out.println("Sorry, but we do not carry that product.");
        }

    } // End of main() method.

} // End of JumpinJive class.
```

Am I missing something or am I misinterpreting possibly what the assignment is going for? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Could you indent your code properly so we can read it? Your IDE can do it for you. Thx.

Comment: I just changed the indentation. Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks for improving the indentation. I polished it yet a bit for you.

Comment: Thank I forgot to get rid of the unnecessary } at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I only get one dialog box to pop up and if I add an XXX it quits the system completely without giving an output

You need some kind of loop, maybe something like...

```
do {
    // Get user input.
    addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: ");
    if (!addIn.equals("XXX")) {
        // Write the rest of the program here.
    }
} while (!addIn.equals("XXX"));
```

I'd recommend having a look at [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) and have a look a the [The while and do-whole statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details

Also, you're not keeping a running total of the order...

So, instead of...

```
System.out.println("Name of the product :" + addIns[it] + "\nPrice of the product:"
        + addInPrices[it]);

//Output the total for the price of the product 
System.out.println("Total Price of the product :" + (orderTotal + addInPrices[it]));
```

Maybe something like...

```
String item = addIns[it];
double price = addInPrices[it];
orderTotal += price;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item + " is $" + price + " - Order total: $" + orderTotal);
```

will keep track of the current order total

And this...

```
if (foundIt) {
    //Prints a Error Message
    System.out.println("Sorry, but we do not carry that product.");
}
```

Is going to display an error message when the item is found (i.e. `if (true) {...}`, you want to negate the question, maybe something like...

```
if (!foundIt) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, but we do not carry that product.");
}
```

Comment: Nice and helpful answer, upvoted. I am not sure the OP asked that it should be possible to have more than one add-in in the coffee, though.

Comment: @OleV.V. I took *"but I only get one dialog box to pop up and if I add an XXX it quits the system completely without giving an output...I know if I add some more addIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter coffee add-in or XXX to quit: "); it would give me another pop-up window"* to basically mean they wanted to keep on asking - but I had to read the question 4 times to come to that conclusion :P